# Function call as argument to C macro

Tags: c++, c, function, macros, arguments

First a little code:

```
int counter = 0;

int get_counter() { return counter++; }

#define EVEN_OR_ZERO(cc) ( (cc) % 2 == 0 ? (cc) : 0 )

int next_even_or_zero = EVEN_OR_ZERO(get_counter());
```

This code might seem OK, but... Let's expand the macro:

```
int next_even_or_zero = get_counter() % 2 == 0 ? get_counter() : 0;
```

As you can see the macro will only return odd numbers - which is the opposite of what was expected (or desired).

The question: Is there any way to get this work as intended with a macro? Or is a regular function the only way to go?

```
//This works as wanted
int even_or_zero(int value) { return value % 2 == 0 ? value : 0; }
```

Comment: In C++ or in C? You've used both tags, which makes it very hard to know what answer you want.

Comment: In C++ at least, macro-functions like this are not a good idea.

Comment: The answer is simple: Don't use a macro, unless there's a good reason for it. This case isn't one of them.

Comment: It would help an awful lot to understand why you want a macro. Does it need to work for types other than `int`? Can we assume the parameter can be duplicated or captured? Etectera.

Comment: You are aware that `get_counter()` gets called twice, aren't you?

Answer (score 3):

```
#define EVEN_OR_ZERO(cc) even_or_zero(cc)
```

This may be the perfect answer or a bad joke, depending on why you need a macro, which you haven't told us.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: Don't use a macro, unless there's a good reason for it. This case isn't one of them:

```
int even_or_zero(int i) {
    if (i % 2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... inline functions is the ticket here (assuming c++)

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions.

```
int getCurrentCounter() { ... } // just return here
int getNextCounter() { ... } // increment here
```

This is how - in example - sequences is PSQL works.

---

Also, this seems like very bad code design.

- don't use macros in C++, there are more better ways to achieve what you want (usally) without using them
- functions with sideeffects on global variables are not that good. Think if it would not be better to create struct/class with it's counter and add methods to it. Or better yet, could hide methods as prive at set methods/class as their friends to limit who can affect counter.